# What is a person who owes you a favour called?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

First of all, English is not my mother tongue. Secondly, I was wondering if there is such a word in the English language that describes a person, who owes you some favour (not really money tho).

Like, for example:

> I did the washing up when it was your turn. You owe me a favour. You are my _______

Can I use words such as *borrower* or *debtor*? Because I feel like it only refers to owing somebody money.

Comment: The full OED does actually list [***debtee***](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/47942?redirectedFrom=debtee#eid), but it's a bit dated / legalistic today. Personally, given the ***-ee*** suffix has gained traction in recent years, I'd probably go for ***indebtee*** in "(semi-)facetious" contexts, because it seems a better match for *owes a **favour*** rather than ***money***. It's not actually in the OED, but that wouldn't bother me, since it would be perfectly well understood by any competent native speaker (the kind I usually interact with! :)

Comment: A common phrase is to say "you owe me", and less common "you are in my debt".

Comment: A [debtor](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/debtor): "one who owes a debt."

Answer (score 2):

**beholden**    [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/beholden)

> Owing something, such as gratitude, to another; indebted.

As in:

> I am **beholden** to you, as you did my job.

or

> Beholden you are, as I did your job!

**beholden to (someone)** the idiom

> Indebted or under obligation to someone, or feeling that one is under
>   such an obligation.

Comment: I *think* OP is asking for a noun, not an adjective. And it would take quite a contrived context to use ***beholden*** as a noun *(Blessed are the beholden, for they shall pay us what they owe).*